RewriteMap on shared host
I want to use RewriteMap on a shared hosting. Based on docs and similar questions, I have to put this inside server config... However, I am confused about all these terms.

In what directories Apache allows me to put that .txt file?
If I don't have access to that special directories, can I put the file anywhere and change the Apache config (by asking hosting support) to read the file from there?
If none of these is possible, is there an alternative? Not apps or php scripts or something, but an easy, out-of-the-box solution just like configuring .htaccess itself.

This is my current .htaccess if it helps:
...
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap blog_redirects "txt:/etc/blog_redirects.txt"

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^old-blog/post$ ${blog_redirects:$1} [L,R=301,QSD]
...

